# Unity show pop up if the player doesn't move for 5 seconds

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a task on Unity 3d that if the player doesn't move for 5 seconds, a pop-up shows on the center of the screen and if the player moves, the pop-up disappears. How can I write the logic for this task please ?
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? How would you do it as a person

Comment: I think I'll have to run a Coroutine for a specified time and do an if statement that if the player moves an action happens and if not the action doesn't happen or stops from happening. I have an idea but I don't know exactly how to implement it.

Comment: This seems like a good solution you have there, why not attempt it and alter your question if you run into any issues

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that will check the mouse position of the user and see if it has moved in the last 5 seconds. If it has not, then the popup window will show up. If it's hard to read here with the comments (I kind of think it is) copy and paste this code into Visual Studio so the colors will help distinguish code from comments.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject popupWindow = null;

float totTime;
float timeBeforePause = 5f;
Vector3 updatedMousePosition;

private void Update()
{
    //  Add the time delta between frames to the totTime var
    totTime += Time.deltaTime;

    //  Check to see if the current mouse position input is equivalent to updateMousePosition from the previous update
    //  If they are equivalent, this means that the user hasn't moved the mouse
    if (Input.mousePosition == updatedMousePosition)
    {
        //  Since the user hasn't moved the mouse, check to see if the total Time is greater than the timeBeforePause
         if (totTime >= timeBeforePause)
        {
            //  Set the popup window to true in order to show the window (instantiate instead it if if doesn't exist already)
            popupWindow.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    //  If the user has moved the mouse, set the totTime back to 0 in order to restart the totTime tracking variable
    else
    {
       totTime = 0;
    }

    //  Check to see if the popup window is visible (active)
    if (popupWindow.activeSelf == true)
    {
        //  Check to see if the user has pressed the Esc button
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            //  Hide the window
            popupWindow.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    //  Update the updatedMousePosition before the next frame/update loop executes
    updatedMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}
```

If you want to track different user input (key presses) you can use a similar method. Also you will have to implement some sort of button on the popup window that will allow the user to exit out from the popup window once they return. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked with the mouse. Is it possible if I don't have to implement a button for it to work with the keyboard please ?

Comment: @AyrtonMicallef Yup, added. Please mark this answer as the correct answer if it works for you. Thanks!